# transform-origin in IE

Tags: d3.js, svg, internet-explorer-11

Does anyone know how to use transform-origin in IE11?
I'm trying to rotate a group in svg using D3js.

This seems to work for Chrome, but not IE.
    `wheel.style('transform-origin', '50%, 50%')`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d particularly note 1.

Answer (score 1):

The transform-origin CSS property on the SVG elements not support on the IE 11 browser. You could check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin). Besides, you could refer to the article to use [transform and rotate attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) to rotate the SVG.